# JSPlumb toolkit licence

Tags: jsplumb

I have a license copy of the toolkit and updated files downloaded from the website into the demo application. However, I keep getting the message "jsPlumb Toolkit evaluation period expired." after few days of play.

Can someone please advise what configuration does it need to activate my license copy?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution. After replacing tgz licensed files I had to run "npm install --force"

I was just doing "npm install" and it was not updating the node_modules